# Add CMS Static Block underneath categories in left sidebar

Tags: cms, xml, static-block, sidebar

Because my category pages are quite empty, I wanted to fill up some space with a Static Block on the left sidebar of the page. I've created a Static Block in the CMS of Magento, and I'm able to place them on the category pages and other pages. I did this by going to Pages in CMS Management in Magento and under "layout" pasting the following code:

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="left_block" before="-">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_block</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Now my Static Block is showing perfectly, but it's appearing *above* the 'Shop By' menu on the same left sidebar. [image: Screenshot of my problem]

Can anybody help me out with placing my new Static Block *underneath* the 'Shop By' (Blader Door) block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is managing block position by

- **after=""**
- **before=""**

tags on layout XML. Find  left filter block name.

### before/after:

before/after are  `layout attributes that we can set that allow us to define the position of` our block inside structure block

Put this `after='yourleftfilterBlockName' instead is before=''`

As per magento rwd theme block name left hand filter is catalog.leftnav

**then your solution is like:**

```
<reference name="left_first"> <!-- use left_first instead of left for rwd theme-->
<block type="cms/block" name="left_block" after="catalog.leftnav">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_block</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Would you perhaps know where I can find the name of the left filter block? I have no clue where I would find it..